# any value in certain key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

In python, I have a dictionary called

```
 d = {('A', 'A', 'A'):1, ('A', 'A', 'B'):1, ('A', 'A', 'C'):1, ('A', 'B', 'A'): 2, ('A', 'B','C'):2, ...}.
```

Is there a simple way to change the values (to 10 for example) of for when the key is, for example, `('A', 'A', _)` where `_` can be any char `A~Z` ?

So, it will look like `{('A', 'A', 'A'):10, ('A', 'A', 'B'):10, ('A', 'A', 'C'):10, ('A', 'B', 'A'): 2, ('A', 'B', 'C'):2, ...}` at the end.

As for now, I'm using a loop with a variable `x` for `('A', 'A', x)`, but I'm wondering if there are such keywords in python.

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: that does not look like a very good data structure to be using ... it would also be helpful for you to post your code that you have already done ...

Answer (score 3):

Just check the first two elements of each tuple, the last is irrelevant unless you specifically want to make sure it is also a letter:

```
for k  in d:
    if k[0] == "A" and k[1] == "A":
        d[k] = 10
print(d)
{('A', 'B', 'A'): 2, ('A', 'B', 'C'): 2, ('A', 'A', 'A'): 10, ('A', 'A', 'C'): 10, ('A', 'A', 'B'): 10}
```

If the last element must also actually be alpha then use str.isalpha:

```
d = {('A', 'A', '!'):1, ('A', 'A', 'B'):1, ('A', 'A', 'C'):1, ('A', 'B', 'A'): 2, ('A', 'B','C'):2}

for k in d:
    if all((k[0] == "A", k[1] == "A", k[2].isalpha())):
        d[k] = 10
print(d)
{('A', 'B', 'A'): 2, ('A', 'B', 'C'): 2, ('A', 'A', '!'): 1, ('A', 'A', 'C'): 10, ('A', 'A', 'B'): 10}
```

There  is no keyword where `d[('A', 'A', _)]=10` will work, you could hack a functional approach using map with python2:

```
d = {('A', 'A', 'A'):1, ('A', 'A', 'B'):1, ('A', 'A', 'C'):1, ('A', 'B', 'A'): 2, ('A', 'B','C'):2}

map(lambda k: d.__setitem__(k, 10) if ((k[0], k[1]) == ("A", "A")) else k, d)

print(d)
{('A', 'B', 'A'): 2, ('A', 'B', 'C'): 2, ('A', 'A', 'A'): 10, ('A', 'A', 'C'): 10, ('A', 'A', 'B'): 10}
```

Or including isalpha:

```
d = {('A', 'A', '!'):1, ('A', 'A', 'B'):1, ('A', 'A', 'C'):1, ('A', 'B', 'A'): 2, ('A', 'B','C'):2}

map(lambda k: d.__setitem__(k, 10) if ((k[0], k[1],k[2].isalpha()) == ("A", "A",True)) else k, d)

print(d)
```

Comment: o now I see what he was trying to do +1 for reading comprehension

Comment: @JoranBeasley. I think it is anyway!

Comment: yea it is manageable with a for loop. What i meant was if there is a keyword in python to make it shorter. Something that looks like d[('A', 'A', _)]=10 to do what I wanted without going to a loop.

Comment: @Sus, no there is no wildcard matching with a dict.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ah that's the term I was looking for, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
for item in d.keys():
    if re.match("\('A', 'A', '[A-Z]'\)",str(item)):
        d[item] = 10
```

This is another method. Returns None in the console, but appears to update the values:

```
[d.update({y:10}) for y in [x for x in d.keys() if re.match("\('A', 'A', '[A-Z]'\)",str(x))]]
```

Comment: Depending on the string representation is unreliable and indirect. Checking the values themselves makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Using a list comprehension to mutate an object doesn't make tons of sense. You can just use a for loop.

Comment: `d.update({y: 10})` seems like a rather funny way to write `d[y] = 10`.